# Declare only once the Use "Namespace" initialization and all files got the same namepace for an object

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, request

I got a simple question for you hopefully. Can it be possible that I just initialize the namespace for a class once in my "main file" and all other objects or classes got the same reference of it ?

For example Index.php:

```
require_once 'init.php';
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

and now I got a class not in the same file with this kind of code. Controller.php:

```
function programmAction($id) {
        $programm = $this->model->getProgrammById($id);
        $html = $this->renderTemplate($this->tempProgramm,['programm' => $programm]);
        return new Response($html);
    }
```

Normally when I don't add the use lines as well to this file I would get an error message that the class Response was not found.

Comment: ill-advised, but you could set `namespace Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;`

Comment: You can also refer to the used classes directly instead: `return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($html)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you include all other classes in the same file. Refer to this note from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> Note:
>   Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

<sub>Please don't include all of your classes in one file.</sub>

It may seem like a pain to retype the `use` statements in each and every class file, but really it will help you when you go back and refer to that file later.  Right at the top is a list of classes that your class *depends* on, and could be helpful information during a refactoring or code reorganization.

Comment: ... but included files inherit the variables from the parent scope... it introduces the same hardness in reading ... who would expect that one file needs a `$x` variable to work ...

Comment: @RoyalBg Using autoloading and an OOP approach, much of the functionality in many apps is wrapped inside of classes that get included from within an autoloader, a function with it's own scope generally removed from the context of the scope that's actually interested in using it. Even still, the question is about inheriting the namespace imports/aliases themselves, and not variable scope. I still think it would be beneficial to see at the top of a class file what other classes it depends on existing. What would be nice is if you could import an entire namespace with one statement though...

Comment: Including files inside another files (or its functions) creates a context for the included file. It's very handy when you include `views` so you can naturally send them a variable e.g. `$model` that contains the information needed for the view to render. Different contexts can require this `view` with different data. It could be the same as in namespaces. Yes, it seems like a hack, but it's a little bit inconsistent if we have in mind the other PHP features. Why shouldn't one be able to include a class from two different location with two different usings (`\a\class` or `\b\class`).

Comment: All the use statements do is create an alias locally in the file. I can very easily need to have to pull functionality in from classes in two different namespaces that happen to both be named `CoolClass`. I would need to alias one to a _different_ name if I want to actually reference both in the same file. Since PSR-4 is the (de facto) standard, if we wanted to include the same class using two different namespaces that file would have to be stored in two different places in the filesystem which is crazy talk, or I'm just misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: Besides, if an included file were to inherit the `use` statements of the file that included it, it would mean that you would loose complete visibility of what class aliases are actually left to you or what anything actually refers to. How many levels deep in the include hierarchy are you? This file includes that file which includes this other file that is the one that actually includes my file. What does `CoolClass` mean in this context? Has it already been aliased yet, or do I need to do it? Now it's 6 months later and I have to refactor. Or I leave and the next guy has to.

Comment: Yes, this is true, and the same problem is about the inherited variables. It's all about consistency. I'm completely agree about the transparency. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126236/discussion-between-jeff-lambert-and-royal-bg).